# Let's have a new feature: No [feature-requests]!

Tags: discussion, tags

On this post: [Closing an inactive feature request?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1305/when-to-close-an-inactive-feature-request)

There are two tags currently on the question: [issue-tracking](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/issue-tracking) and [feature-requests](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-requests).

[issue-tracking](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/issue-tracking) looks like an excellent tag to me, but then what is the point of the [feature-requests](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-requests)?

Comment: Change main, change SE, but never change yourself... (referencing meta)

Comment: For those who don't understand, I'm referencing two downvotes to this discussion question.

Comment: For three downvotes, and a single upvote... Have I asked something wrong?

Comment: I guess people think there's a use case for distinguishing questions about `[feature-requests]` specifically from general `[issue-tracking]` questions? I'm not 100% sold on the usefulness of the distinction, but it's not a totally crazy idea, either.

Comment: I was just awfully confused about the tag, and I'm interested in hearing any thoughts, or ideas as to what it's purpose will be, as well as it's rationale for creation. That said, thank you @apsillers for your thoughts :D

Answer (score 2):

As a maintainer of several free software projects I frequently receive feature requests through our project's issue tracker system.

Dealing with feature requests is *different* from dealing with bug reports and pull-requests (the two other main type of issues that appear).  I really would love to see questions that would help maintainers such as myself learn how to *better* deal with feature requests (examples: how and when to reject or oblige, how to monetize on feature requests, how to motivate the users to contribute to feature requests, etc.)

While the question linked to by the OP could do with some *improvement* (something that did not happen), I hope to see more of these questions, so my opinion is that we should let this tag live.